# Get combined value for a column that has distinct values for other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want a combined value of a column if multiple rows have same value in other columns.

For e.g. in figure below upto 4<sup>th</sup> row there are only two distinct records if I exclude **Type *Column*.**

[image]

Since I need **type *column*** I want to combine 2 rows type into one so expected output would be
[image]

What would be the equivalent sql for this output from above 6 records result set.

Comment: @DavidG, oops, didn't read carefully enough... Sorry OP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  If you don't care about the ordering of the values:

```
select a, b, c, d, e,
       (case when min(f) = max(f) then min(f)
             else min(f) + '-' + max(f)
        end) as new_f
from t
group by a, b, c, d, e;
```

Comment: Thanks got what I was looking for.